# Code in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

Good day! So, I need to present my disertation code to my thesis advisors, but I'm quite unsure how to actually do it in a proper way. I found [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/LookAtMySlides/codeware) showing some ideas.

Is there a way of making the slides 48-67 in beamer without using tikz? Any ideas to implement the whole ideas the author propose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid that you may find it difficult to get help with the current state of your question. First, a question on this site should be self-contained and not rely on external links, which don't remain useful when their content changes. Second, posting an example with 67+ slides is sure to put people off: how much time do you think people will want to spend answering one question? Third, you're asking to re-code 19 of those slides and to implement an unspecified number of the author's (unimplemented?) ideas. The mind-reading alone is a major project: not an answer on this site.

Comment: Please make a minimal document which illustrates a specific issue you want help with, post the code and format it by highlighting and using ctrl+k. Then explain the particular question you have about that code. This will make it much easier for people to understand the problem and try out solutions - and so much more likely they will.

Comment: To the close-voters: wait a few days before closing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSY4.png. 
Let's give the OP time to refine his/her question!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @CarLaTeX This flowchart is ridiculous and pointless.  If the question is bad, I vote to close.  If there is an edit making the question valid, I vote to reopen.

Comment: @HenriMenke The flowchart is Paulo Cereda's. The question (as is) is to be closed, but not at once, let's give the OP some time to refine it. See also here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2743/101651.

Answer (score 17):

You can add code in the same way as in "normal" latex documents, for example using the `listings` package or `minted`.

One thing to do: you have to use the `[fragile]` option for frames containing code.

A quick example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{lstlisting}
       %CODE HERE
   \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(to adjust the colours etc. as in the slides you linked to, have a look at the `listings` documentation)